# fs.unlink doesn't delete the file

Tags: node.js, express, fs

On my Express server I want to take the file uploaded by the user and rename it to match their username. If the username uploads a new file, the previous file is replaced.

Here's the code:

```
  var newPath = 'uploads/' + user.username + '.' + (file.extension).toLowerCase();
  var basePath = path.resolve(__dirname + '../../../') + '/';

  // Copy, rename and delete temp file
  var is = fs.createReadStream(basePath + file.path);
  var os = fs.createWriteStream(basePath + newPath);

  is.pipe(os);
  is.on('end', function (error) {
    if (err) return res.send(500);
    fs.unlink(basePath + file.path);
  });
```

Problem is that `fs.unlink(basePath + file.path);` doesn't actually delete the old file on my machine (OSX 10.9.2). How can i make sure the temp file is deleted?

Comment: Simpler to just use a single `fs.rename` call, no?

Comment: @PeterLyons tried that and had the same problem.

Comment: Did you try adding a callback to `fs.unlink()` to see if `err` is set? Also, you might want to listen for 'close' instead of 'end' for the file readable stream, since that indicates the backing fd is actually closed.

Answer (score 2):

The file `basePath + file.path` has link reference by the read stream `is`. The removal of the file contents shall be postponed until all references to the file are closed. You might want to call `fs.unlink` on the `close` event.

Comment: Also note that if you are using **fs.readFileSync** do not pass a fileName as string. It will not close it automatically. So if you are creating a temporary file use `let fd = fs.openSync(fileName); responseFileContents = fs.readFileSync(fd, 'utf8');` by passing an integer to _fs.readFileSync_ you ensure it to close. Further reading: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/95266db2bc4d1cf1ab7d63aeed1a728124ead298/lib/fs.js#L387-L388

Answer (score 0):

I just use `fs.writeFile` which overwrites a file. I have code in my app to this synchronously, but it looks like this:

```
if( !fs.existsSync( filename ) )  fs.openSync( filename, "wx" );
fs.writeFileSync( filename, data );
```

Basically I check if the file exists, and if it doesn't I open it. Then, I just write to the file. If it is new or already existing, only my `data` is present in the file when I look at it, overwriting what was there.

Comment: Calling existsSync, then openSync isn't good - the file can be removed between the 2 calls.Docs for writeFile says "writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists" (writeFileSync is just a synchronous version). Doesn't that do what you want without the existsSync or openSync being there at all?