# File stay in my folder after deleting but deleted after restart Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a function that loops over an array that contains paths to files, then I delete each of them.
The files are uploaded with Multer in a folder "assets/temp/"
Here is my delete method using fs :

```
exports.unlinkFiles = (filesPathsArr) => {
    try {
        filesPathsArr.forEach((filePath) => {
            if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
               fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
               console.log('File deleted : ', filePath)
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

My input for example :

```
['assets\temp\pexelsphoto19886811645117462309.jpg', 'assets\temp\relaxtriptest1645118333937.mp3']
```

My output :

```
File Deleted : assets\temp\pexelsphoto19886811645117462309.jpg
File Deleted : assets\temp\relaxtriptest1645118333937.mp3
```

But in my folder temp :

[image]

**+ And if I try to open the file, it say 'Enable to read..'**

**+ When I restart the server, the file just disapear**

Is this just a local problem with my machine, maybe the problem will go away in production? Or maybe it's just a small detail that I shouldn't worry about? Or is it something else ?

Comment: Did you verify the file exists via Terminal?  It is possible that your IDE is just being helpful.

Comment: Yes I checked and the file does exist in my folders on the disk, but yet when I try to open it the file seems corrupted, it seems that it cannot delete it completely at first.

Comment: have you tried using the async version of fs.unlinkSync?  like:
`var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink('C:\path\to\my\file\test1.txt', (err) => {});`

Comment: Yes I tried that and no error, it simply returns the `console.log('File deleted', filePath)`

Comment: hmmm.  My current theory is that is has something to do with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32773995/3597730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem !

After uploading the file with Multer, I upload it to AWS S3.

But the problem is that if there is an error with the AWS code, then I throw an exception and then delete the uploaded files from the temporary directory. But by doing this, I didn't let the AWS function finish and so the readstream was still open.

The solution then was to `myReadStreamCreated.destroy()` at the end of the function and also in the catch of the try catch bloc, if an exception is thrown, to allow fs.unlink to be able to delete the file correctly.

Thank's to [ruby-newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597730/ruby-newbie)